# Tif data converted in to LAZ or LAS format

Tags: python, geotiff, lidar

Being completely ignorant to Lidar data, I am using an open source application https://github.com/chadrockey/TGC-Designer-Tools written in Python, to generate Golf Courses in a game utilizing this awesome app. The problem arises when the data is only available in tif format, which cannot be used in the program.  It has to be in Laz or Las format.

I have read that the elevation data is actually built in to the tif file itself?  From what I read, you cannot "convert" a tiff files data in to laz or las format.  Please advise how I can utilize tif images and get it pulled in to the tool mentioned above.

Comment: Are you sure there are no point cloud data for your area of interest? Converting a digital elevation model to laz/Las format would be messy. Best case scenario, you convert your raster grid to points and write to las format. Not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Borealis.  I figured it would be a difficult or impossible task.

Comment: @NobleMan I am also using "Chad's Tool" to make golf courses.  I have successfully converted DTM ascii files to Las's and imported them (LanglandBay in Wales for example).    I have used RapidLasso's command line tools to convert and classify data.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a geotiff DTM file to las or laz by using CloudCompare (opensource).

Comment: Philippe, hello, thanks for the answer and welcome to stackoverflow. It would be helpful for future references if you would expand the answer and describe the specific converting procedure